# Setting up LibPostal (JPostal) on Windows in Java

Tags: java, c, windows, maven, gradle

I'm trying to setup [libpostal](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal)/[jpostal](https://github.com/openvenues/jpostal) on my Windows 10 machine in a Java environment. I followed the [Windows Installation Guide on GitHub](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal#installation-windows).

I am able to see the `libpostal` folder installed under: `C:\xxx\Program Files\libpostal\` with sub folders: `.git`, `autom4te.cache`, `data`, `m4`, `resources` etc.

However, when I run:

```
AddressExpander expander = AddressExpander.getInstance();
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jpostal_expander in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at com.mapzen.jpostal.AddressExpander.<clinit>(AddressExpander.java:7)
    at jpostal.JPostal.execute(JPostal.java:24)
    at global_projects.GlobalMain.main(GlobalMain.java:37)
```

I normally use Maven for my build. However, since [there is currently no Maven repository for JPostal](https://github.com/openvenues/jpostal/issues/7), I am using Gradle.

I followed the solution suggested on [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/openvenues/jpostal/issues/3) by adding [the following gradle.build file](https://github.com/openvenues/jpostal/blob/master/build.gradle#L18), however I still get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error means that it tries to load a native library called `jpostal_expander` and it can't find. It would likely be called `jpostal_expander.dll`. This could mean that you didn't properly build it. I don't know jpostal, so I can't help you on that.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this issue ?