# Command Not Found when Installing JPostal on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, bash, command-line

I'm trying [to setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71202369/setting-up-libpostal-jpostal-on-windows-in-java?noredirect=1#comment125860194_71202369) [JPostal](https://github.com/openvenues/jpostal) + [LibPostal](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal#installation-windows) on a Windows 10 PC.

[JPostal documentation states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71202369/setting-up-libpostal-jpostal-on-windows-in-java?noredirect=1#comment125860194_71202369) that the following command must execute without errors:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs libpostal
```

However, when I execute the above command I get the following error:

```
bash: pkg-config command not found
```

The documentation did not state to install any other software to execute the above command. Is there something missing? I'm on Windows 10.

**Update**:

I re-read [the documentation](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal#installation-maclinux) on `libpostal` which states:

> `libpostal` has support for `pkg-config`, so you can use the
> pkg-config to print the flags needed to link your program against it..

It seems like once I install `libpostal` the above command should work. Why isn't it working?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bash: pkg-config command not found
```

shows that you are using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) or Cygwin. In either case, you will first have to install the pkg-config package using the command below. Afterward, the setup shall work.

```
sudo apt install pkg-config
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am now getting `Package libpostal was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing libpostal.pc
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package libpostal, required by 'virtual:world', not found` do you have any idea [how to solve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71214833/pkg-config-libpostal-cannot-find-package-in-pkg-config-search-path)?